# As a president of a rocket club for my university. If I apply for internship/job for a petroleum company. Would this work out?

Tags: aerospace-engineering

So I'm the president of my unis rocket club. The thing is, petroleum jobs got money and although I would apply for aeronautical companies first, just as a backup. I wanna apply for the petroleum companies. Do you guys think that this can work out? If it can't work out, may I know why? And if maybe, what I should do then?

Comment: The answer is much like your other question.  It might help a bit, but what is important is your class work and grades compared to the job description.

Answer (score 2):

To repeat my previous answer, but in blunter terms since you ask the same question again:

Interviewers don't have any interest in what fancy titles you give yourself.

The interesting thing is what you, and the club you claim to be president of, ***actually did.***

Nobody expects a would-be petroleum engineer to have spent his/her spare time digging for oil. What counts is doing *something* that is practical engineering, or managing a practical engineering project.

Comment: I like your answer except I’d like to point out that no one is hiring a college summer intern to manage.